# Google Analytics behaving strange with Extensionless URL

Tags: google-analytics

We have a site, that is experiencing double tracking like symptons.

http://www.marilyn.ca/cibc
or http://www.marilyn.ca/Cooking

If you pull up fiddler, you will notice that you get 2 responses back from Google Analytics. But if you look at it closely. 
The UTMP parameters are actually different

One is /CIBC, the other is /CIBC/

With this site in particular, it is extensionless URL. We don't have the problem with other sites that don't have extensionless URL. Is there a way to get around this and get it fixed?

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your sites in google analytics debugger and as you mentioned there are 2 calls being made to GIF request one with page as /cibc and next with page as /cibc/ . The problem might be caused the jquery address javascript in your pages, which must be adding the trailing slash and triggering the second call to GA. Please remove  `jquery.address-1.3.1.min.js` and check that the 2nd call is removed.

Comment: but jquery.address plug in provides deep links and we probably really need that.

Comment: Ok, I removed jquery.address, and it works sometimes locally, i would get "Track Pageview" in Chrome, but not the rest of the response back.